# Modelsim not recognizing an architecture including "case...when"

Tags: architecture, vhdl, modelsim

I'm pretty new to Modelsim, and i keep getting this "error" from it. Basically i coded a counter with vhdl:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Contatore16bit is
 port (
  CLK: in std_logic;
  RESET: in std_logic;
  LOAD: in std_logic;
  UP_DOWN: in std_logic;
  ENABLE: in std_logic;
  USCITA: out unsigned(15 downto 0) );
end Contatore16bit;

architecture Arch of Contatore16bit is
 signal temp_value, next_value: unsigned(15 downto 0);
 begin
  process (CLK)
   begin
    if CLK'Event and CLK='1' then
     if RESET='1' then
      temp_value <= (others => '0');
     elsif ENABLE='1' then
      temp_value <= next_value;
     end if;
    end if;
   --CASE UP_DOWN IS
    --WHEN  '0'  =>  next_value <= temp_value + conv_unsigned(1, 16);
    --WHEN  '1'  =>  next_value <= temp_value - conv_unsigned(1, 16);
   --END CASE;
   --CASE LOAD IS
    --WHEN  '0'  =>  USCITA <= conv_unsigned(0, 16);
    --WHEN  '1'  =>  USCITA <= temp_value;
   --END CASE;
  end process;
end Arch;
```

I can start a simulation without any problem with this code. However, if I decomment the "case" lines, modelsim wont recognise the architecture anymore and will give me the error:

> Error: (vsim-3173) Entity
>   '...Contatore\simulation\modelsim\rtl_work.contatore16bit' has no
>   architecture.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: 1) The Case statements should probably be in the clocked part of the process! 2) Use numeric_std.unsigned instead of std_logic_unsigned, and write `next_value <= temp_value + 1;` - much tidier!

Comment: Is next_value/USCITA meant to change simultaneously with temp_value, or one cycle after temp_value? If the latter case do as Brian says otherwise the case statements should be moved out of the process. (You can't mix synchronous and asynchronous assignments in the same process, synthesis tools will generally not understand what to do if you try.)

Answer (score 7):

That's not the error I get.  Mine is more informative:

```
** Error: test.vhd(28): (vcom-1339) Case statement choices cover only 2 out of 9 cases.
** Error: test.vhd(32): (vcom-1339) Case statement choices cover only 2 out of 9 cases.
```

This is because `std_logic` has many other values than '1' and '0' - specifically:

- `U` - uninitalised
- `X` - conflicted
- `Z` - high-impedance
- `W` - weak high impedance
- `H` - weak pullup
- `L` - weak pulldown
- `-` - don't care
- `1` - strong high
- `0` - strong low

One of the rules of VHDL is that you must say what you want to do for every possible input value.  One way of doing this is to use

```
when others =>
```

If you want nothing in particular to happen for the other inputs, you can use the `null` statement to say so.

The synthesiser will then optimise this to just the values you have specified.